# Cross compilling .deb package for yocto image?i.e remot3.it

Tags: ssh, debian, cross-compiling, yocto

I am new to yocto development. I have a yocto image installed on an armv7 based device. I need some kind of a software to ssh the device through internet. Previously i were using remot3.it service/software on my raspberryPI and now i need something similar for my yocto image. Is there any recipe already available for yocto pyro branch which can meet this requirement? and if not can i cross compile remot3.it for my yocto image?
I tried to build from source through this link..
https://github.com/remoteit/installer/tree/master/Raspbian%20deb/1.3-07
but it need dependencies of "mawk" and "cron" which is absent.
I searched for these two recipes of "mawk" and "cron" but havent found any.

Can somebody help me what should i do?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it looks like there is nothing to compile - only binaries are provided. And if the binaries do not match your target architecture/OS, they will not run, or run with obscure errors. Raspbian is not the same as Yocto-based distro.

You can simply add a ssh server (dropbear or openssh are both provided) to your target image, although this does not scale to 'device management solution' that remot3.it provides.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply... i dont have a static ip and i need something like remot3.it to ssh my devices over internet but not sure how can i configure openssh server to do that..can i do that through openssh?